# CRS of QGIS CAD tool and measure line tool

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, distance, cad

Does any one know what CRS the QGIS digitizing toolbox (CAD tool) and the measure line tool use?

Because I couldn't find any way to manually set the CRS for the tools in QGIS 3, my assumption is that it will use the CRS set for the QGIS project. But I am seeing inconsistent values of the two tools when setting the project CRS to EPSG 3857 (Pseudo-Mercator). While the CAD tool shows a distance of 5m, the measure line tool only measures a distance of 3.3m.

Comment: I'd say the measurement tool was doing you a favor, by indicating how inaccurate notorious Web Mercator is at that location.

Answer (score 1):

The [Advanced Digitizing Panel](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#the-advanced-digitizing-panel) use the project CRS, and it must be a projected system.

> The tools are not enabled if the map view is in geographic coordinates.
>
> If you want to draw a segment of a given length, click the d (distance) text box (keyboard shortcut D), type the distance value (in map units) and press Enter.

---

The [Measuring Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#measuring) measures the ellipsoidal length, and the ellipsoid and units can be defined in the project properties.

> The default measurement metric is ellipsoidal, using the ellipsoid defined in Project ‣ Properties… ‣ General. This is true both when geographic and projected coordinate systems are defined for the project.